# Select all rows where a column contains two or more times a string

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a `Player` table with a column named `Info`.

Is it possible to select all rows in `Player` where the `Info` column contains the word `"foo"` *two or more times*?

Comment: Something like `SELECT Info FROM Player WHERE Info LIKE '%foo%'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes of course,in your where clause just write `foo` two or more times between `%` signs:

```
where Info like '%foo%foo%'
```